# How do I use promises in node.js to clean up a chain of callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, q

I'm trying to figure out how to use promises, particularly the Q implementation to clean up some messy nested callbacks in a node.js program. Unfortunately, there seems to be very few simple examples out there that illustrate what I'd like to do.

Here is a simplified version of the nested callbacks I have now:

```
    var parent = this;
    this.receiveMessage(params, function(err, request) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else {
       parent.handleMessage(request, function(response) {
           parent.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(response), function() {
               console.log("response sent");
               var params = { ReceiptHandle:request.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle };
               parent.deleteMessage(params, function() {
                   parent.waitForMessage();
               });
           });
       });
    }
});
```

As you can see this is pretty messy and has 4 levels of nested callbacks.

Using Q, I've figured out that you start with something like:

```
Q.nfcall(this.connection.receiveMessage, params)
    .then(function(err, request) {
        return(Q.nfcall(this.handleMessage(request));
    })
    .then(function(response)) { 
        return(Q.nfcall(this.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(response))));
    } ...
```

and so on... but this doesn't seem quite right. First, do I need to call Q.nfcall  on each function in my chain? Also, do I avoid the scoping issues with "this" that I get when I use callbacks? Am I even using promises the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues and I realized later it was because of Q. In my opinion Q has a messy API and it's cumbersome to use with very few simple examples. I recommend trying any other library, though I do recommend Bluebird. With Bluebird you could do the following:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var parent = this;
Promise.promisifyAll(parent, { suffix: "P" });
parent.receiveMessageP(params)
  .then(function (request) {
    return [request, parent.handleMessageP(request)];
  })
  .spread(function (request, response) {
    return [request, parent.sendMessageP(JSON.stringify(response))];
  })
  .spread(function (request) {
    console.log("response sent");
    var params = { ReceiptHandle: request.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle };
    return parent.deleteMessageP(params);
  })
  .then(function () {
    parent.waitForMessage();
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  });
```

If you don't like the style of returning arrays and using `.spread`, you can use a mapping object in your outer scope.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var parent  = this;
Promise.promisifyAll(parent, { suffix: "P" });
var cache = {};
parent.receiveMessageP(params)
  .then(function (request) {
    cache.request = request;
    return parent.handleMessageP(request);
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    return parent.sendMessageP(JSON.stringify(response));
  })
  .then(function () {
    console.log("response sent");
    var params = { ReceiptHandle: cache.request.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle };
    return parent.deleteMessageP(params);
  })
  .then(function () {
    parent.waitForMessage();
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  });
```

If you need access to variables later in the chain that were resolved earlier in the chain, you can simply keep adding them to the `cache` object for easy access. Sometimes if you have a lot of those, this method is cleaner and easier to read. I usually prefer the first example in most cases, just to avoid polluting the parent scope and potentially holding onto references that should otherwise be disposed of.

Not that you can't do something similar to `promisifyAll` in Q, but Bluebird is more performant and more intuitive.

If your callbacks don't conform to the typical node style signature of `function (err, successValue)` (which some of yours don't appear to, which means `promisifyAll` won't work on them) then you can define a custom "promisifier" in Bluebird. Either that or modify your callback API to conform to [node-style callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/).

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#option-promisifier

Comment: Notice that `handleMessage`, `sendMessage` and `deleteMessage` don't actually adhere to node callback conventions

Comment: I did notice that, but they are obviously custom methods in his app. Most likely he would be able to "nodeify" his own API. Regardless, even if not, the point of my answer was to offer an alternative to Q because it's API is far more intuitive and better documented. I'm sure this answer is a decent enough start. Bluebird supports custom promisify functions for its promisifyAll method.

Comment: Hm, if they are his own methods, he'd better promisify them :-)

Comment: …but stated it didn't work (and is indeed completely wrong - `this` issue, arguments passed to wrong function)

Comment: Um no, he didn't say it didn't work. Read it again. He asked how not to have to use nfcall every time.

Comment: Ooops, you're right. But his code just obviously can't have worked :-)

Comment: No, not custom methods in my app. I left out the err object as I didn't know it was required and I tried to provide a simplified example without all the clutter.

Comment: Well there you go :-)

Answer (score 1):

Promises do let you unnest the callbacks, but applying `nfcall` inline is cumbersome. You can apply `nbind` as a decorator to the original function, so you can use it as a promise returning function to build a chain:

```
obj.receiveMessage = Q.nbind(obj.receiveMessage, obj);
obj.deleteMessage = ...
```

It will read better now:

```
this.receiveMessage(params)
  .then(function(request) {
    return parent.handleMessage(request);
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    var params = {ReceiptHandle: request.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle};
    return parent.deleteMessage(params);
  })
  .then(parent.waitForMessage)
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  });
```

Comment: Notice that `handleMessage`, `sendMessage` and `deleteMessage` don't actually adhere to node callback conventions

Comment: Notice also that the call to `request.Messages[0]` in the second `then` handler would result in `Cannot call Messages[0] of undefined`. You need to pass `request` down the chain by returning an array from the first and second handlers, and using `spread` instead of `then` to spread the results of the array into multiple arguments for the next handler in the chain. See my answer for an example; Q has the same ability.

Comment: How do they not adhere to node callback conventions? Is it because they must all take an err and data? If that is the case, well, they actually do, but I didn't put the err object in here for simplicities sake. I was not aware that that was a requirement of node.